# Need Admissible heuristics for AI problem

Tags: algorithm

I need help to figure out a simple heuristics (which is admissible / never overestimates), using A* search, for the AI problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigdge_ah_problem

Please note: I have implemented the advanced problem where I can pick as many people I want on each side, set the bridge capacity to any value and chose the end position of the torch. Also, the goal could be any situation (one of the sides doesn't necessary needs to be empty - maybe it must end with 2 people on left and 5 people on the right for example).

What should be the logic behind it which never overestimates?

Comment: Don't do that! You answer can help another people. Keep your original question and title.

Comment: Not sure why you're vandalising your own question. If there's some legit reason why you don't want others to see it you can always cast a *close* vote. But I don't think it's fair considering the time taken by Nathan S. to compose an answer.

Comment: Because I want to further edit it later on with many more details, at the moment it is not great, please leave it to me to edit it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways of building heuristics:

One common way of building heuristics is to relax the original problem definition to allow new actions that couldn't previously be taken. Doing so can only make the solution shorter, so we can use this to get an admissible heuristic. The current problem limits that only two people can be on the bridge at once and that they need the torch to cross the bridge. If you relax both requirements you just take the maximum time it will take someone on the original side to cross, and that will give you an admissible heuristic. That is, you assume they just all cross and you're done.

Example 1:

> Original: A B C D [torch]
>
> Goal:
>
> Heuristic: 8 minutes (max of 1, 2, 5, 8)

Example 2:

> Original: A B C
>
> Goal: D [torch]
>
> Heuristic: 5 minutes (max of 1, 2, 5)

You can do slightly better by relaxing just one of these - they still need the torch, but that any number of people can be on the bridge. If the torch is on the original side, that's the heuristic above. Otherwise you can add the minimum time to get the torch back to the original side to your total. (And, if the torch is with someone slow, that slow person will be part of the heuristic calculations both ways.)

Example 3:

> Original: A B C
>
> Goal: D [torch]
>
> Heuristic: 16 minutes (8 to get D across with the torch, 8 to get everyone back)

Example 4:

> Original: C D
>
> Goal: A B [torch]
>
> Heuristic: 9 minutes (1 to get A across with the torch, 8 to get everyone back)

Another way is to abstract the problem into a subproblem (with just k out of N total people in the abstract problem) and exhaustively solve it. Then, a heuristic for the current state is the cost of the solution for the k people in the abstract problem. You can do multiple abstractions and take the max to get better heuristics this way.

Comment: @TeodorNarliyski I've updated the answer with examples that should make it clearer.